# Info about gpg setup on MacOS

Tags: gnupg, macos

On `Mac OS` Mojave:

```
▶ gpg --list-keys
Warning: Failed to set locale category LC_NUMERIC to en_GR.
Warning: Failed to set locale category LC_TIME to en_GR.
Warning: Failed to set locale category LC_COLLATE to en_GR.
Warning: Failed to set locale category LC_MONETARY to en_GR.
Warning: Failed to set locale category LC_MESSAGES to en_GR.
/Users/pkaramol/.gnupg/pubring.kbx
----------------------------------------------
pub   rsa2048 2019-07-04 [SC] [expires: 2021-07-03]
      1DA2A2434A38D1192A3EA4523FEF5E3944A2F025
uid           [ultimate] pkaramol <pkaramol@gmail.com>
sub   rsa2048 2019-07-04 [E] [expires: 2021-07-03]


~/Desktop
▶ ls ~/.gnupg
openpgp-revocs.d  private-keys-v1.d pubring.kbx       pubring.kbx~      trustdb.gpg
```

From what I understand, the public key is : `/Users/pkaramol/.gnupg/pubring.kbx`

How can I find out what is the **corresponding** private key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pubring.kbx` is the public key **database**. Private keys are in `private-keys-v1.d/`. As the `pubring.kbx` contains **all** public keys, there is no such thing as a "corresponding" private key.

To interact with the keyring, you will have to use the `gpg` command. `gpg -k` will list the public keys, while `gpg -K` lists the private keys. When a public and private key have the same ID, they are corresponding key pair.

If you need the key(s) as a file, you can use `gpg --export` for public keys and `gpg --export-secret-keys`. You can also specify the key that you like to export, or use the `-a` option to get an ASCII (plaintext) output.